# Why is it a quadratic equation?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

In [Groth-Sahai NIZK](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/155) proof system, they have defined something called Quadratic Equation in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as shown below. But, my idea of quadratic equation was a second order polynomial equation in a single variable, something of the form $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$. Then how is the below equation a quadratic one?

[image]

Comment: Of course! It's a quadratric equation in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ but in matrix form.

Answer (score 3):

$ax^2+bx+c=0$ is the general expression of a quadratic equation in one variable. Here, there are more than one. You may want to look into how the degree of a multivariate polynomial is defined.